# Creating Procedures with Transactions using PGAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin-4

I'm coming from a long history with SQL Server and trying to learn PL/PGSQL. I've recently discovered the PG11 feature CREATE PROCEDURE which allows for internal transactions inside their body.

As a learning exercise, I've created this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_proc();
CREATE PROCEDURE test_proc()
       LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
  BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a;
    CREATE TABLE a (aid int);
    COMMIT;
  END;
$$;

call test_proc();
```

It works fine in PSQL, however when I execute it in PGAdmin 4's Query Tool, it errors with

> ERROR:  invalid transaction termination
>
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_proc() line 5 at COMMIT
>
> SQL state: 2D000

Can someone please explain what's going on? I'm guessing that the PROCEDURE is in fact valid and the issue might be in the query tool might be incorrectly processing the contained COMMIT.

Are there any suggestions for working around this?

Thanks!

Comment: what query you execute which give you error

Comment: Hi. I'm executing the set of queries that I posted above.

Comment: have you create your store procedure first and you getting error  when you creating

Comment: That is correct. It fails when I create the procedure. If I remove the commit (which I believe is valid to be in there), it works.

Comment: Replace Keyword  PROCEDURE with Function

Comment: I'm not convinced that it's PGAdmin's fault anymore. I've created a procedure using PSQL and am seeing similar behaviour. I assume it's something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I've created a similar question here. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249446/unable-to-create-commit-inside-postgresql-11-5-procedure

Answer (score 0):

In Pgadmin CREATE PROCEDURE as FUNCTION 
please try this by Replace  PROCEDURE with Function and add Return type also and it will work

```
DROP FUNCTION  IF EXISTS test_proc();
CREATE FUNCTION  test_proc()
RETURNS VOID 
LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $$
  BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a;
    CREATE TABLE a (aid int);
    COMMIT;
  END;
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks Harkesh. In this case, I'm trying to use a procedure because I want the ability to create multiple transactions. This is a good overview. https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tech-preview-postgresql-11-create-procedure/
I know that it's kind of a contrived example that I've given, however it's just as a learning exercise.

Comment: if you think this is something you looking for then i will suggest you different solutions

Comment: if your using pgadmin 4.12 and move then same is work that you posted not need to change

Comment: I'm using pgadmin 4.13 with Postgres 11.5. The script works in PSQL, it doesn't work in PGAdmin.

Comment: but i run same in my 4.12 is work fine without any error

Comment: hmmm.. with CREATE PROCEDURE or CREATE FUNCTION?

Comment: with CREATE PROCEDURE

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps 4.13 broke it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try unchecking auto commit & auto rollback options in pgAdmin4?

You can find drop down near Execute button in the query tool.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I did try that. In fact I tried all combinations. I'm seeing the same behaviour.

Comment: Then report this issue to developers https://www.pgadmin.org/support/list/

Comment: Good idea. Thanks.

Comment: @DamienSawyer Refer https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/pg-phriday-stored-procedures-postgres-11/ it says CALL is only valid within its own context, so I think it is expected.